# Is there any way to display only info on update screen?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Here is my update / edit screen on customers area Backpack's admin panel.

[image]

ID's field type like text but it just disabled and readonly.

But when i try to save changes, it doesn't work.  I think its my primary column and can't changable.

```
    $fields =
    [
        [ 'name' => 'id', 'label' => 'ID', 'type' => 'text', 'hint' => __('dashboard.crud_listing.customers.hint_of_id'), 'attributes' => ['disabled' => 'disabled', 'readonly' => 'readonly'], 'fake' => true],

    ];

    $this->crud->addFields($fields);
```

Can anyone have any idea about displaying some data, without saving on this ?

Comment: should be like that, id is autoinc. column. i just want to display to give some information about editor. https://prnt.sc/uyqzcq i really dont want to change it. i just want to show what that is .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you setting '`readonly'  => 'readonly'` inside the 'attributes':

like in [doc](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#text):

you should set as like:

```
[   // Text
    'name'  => 'id',
    'label' => "ID",
    'type'  => 'text',
'readonly'  => 'readonly',
],
```

Comment: oh my god. so many thanks @omr that was my fault 